# Java annotation cannot access protected static fields from upper class

Tags: java, compiler-construction, annotations, java-6

Is this code valid?

```
public abstract class A {
   protected static final String c = "my const";
}

@myAnnotation(value=A.c)
public class B extends A {

}
```

`Eclipse` with JDK 1.6.0.23 accepts this, but `Maven` 2.2.1 with JDK 1.6.0.23 shows me the following compile error:

> c has protected access in A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what is happening here. An instance of an annotations is effectively an interface with a unique static initializer. The only things the annotation spec adds on top are syntactic sugar and a link to the method, class or field. So when you type `value=c.A` that is almost like adding a static initilizer to the annotation. The annotation is not a subclass of A, so access is denied. Protected access includes package access, so when you move A into the same package as B the annotation is also in the same package as A. It gets access. Very good question and I think the behavior should be the same for both compilers. I think Eclipse will let you customize what it treats as an error so you might be able to make them agree to both use the undesirable, more restrictive behavior.

Comment: I think it should be "instance initializer", not "static initializer". And it's not the same as having implicit instance initializer since it is always declared inside a class declaration (that is not true here).

Comment: Here is why I say "almost like a static initializer". An annotation is metadata about code. All code in Java is effectively static (per-class, not per-instance). Therefore, metadata about code is logically static.

And I say "syntactic sugar" because it looks almost like a parameter passed to a constructor, because that is a useful way to write it. But as stated above, it is not like that.

Comment: I'm not so happy with this answer I gave. It is an interesting way to think about why annotations work the way they do, but as the comment from @pingw33n demonstrates it is subjective. Please see my alternate answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comment from @adranale I found a different answer in the Java Language Specification section on [Access Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/names.html#6.6.2). I don't think it should work this way, but the relevant text regarding "protected" reads

Let C be the class in which a protected member m is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.

The body of a class is all the code in curly brackets. Class anotations are outside the curly brackets, so they don't have access. Interestingly, this logic would not apply to method, parameter, field or local variable annotations which are inside the class body.

Answer (score 2):

The Annotation you are trying to fill with the "const" tries to access the class from outside by using protected that can't work. Eclipse uses it's own compiler so you should try to make clean rebuild in Eclipse to see if it's working. I assume it will not.

Comment: It didn't work even after clean. I am wondering why Eclipse does not commit itself to the JDK standard!

Comment: I have checked that as well and was astonished the same way as you. And the answer is true to have both classes within the same package works and if the classes are in different packages it will produce an error in Eclipse. That means the Eclipse compiler behaves differently from the JDK compiler which seemed to be a little bit strange.

Comment: @adranale eclipse always had its own compiler and the JDK one does not represent the standard (it has its own set of bugs), the standard is defined by the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 1):

This code will compile only if both `A` and `B` belong to the same package.

Comment: Hm. Shouldn't that work only if the protected is omitted ? Which means in other words to have package global access.

Comment: It shouldn't change anything. Protected includes package (aka default) scope.

Comment: Is it maybe because the annotation is then accessing `A.c` using the package scope and not using the protected scope of the class `B`?

Comment: Thanks @JohnWatts . Please add your explanation as a separate answer so I accept it.